# Consulta trae todos los registros de una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo un total de 4 tablas

- `Empleados`
- `Subcanales`(Tiendas)
- `EmpleadoTienda` (relacion varios a varios entre subcanales y empleados)
- `VentasMovil` (historial de ventas)

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta donde me traiga el nombre, apellido, nombre de la tienda, y nombre del sub subcanal para cada empleado.

El problema que tengo es que en la tabla ventasMovil existe muchos registro y cuando hago el query me trae todos los registros y eso es lo que quiero evitar, solo quiero que me traiga el nombre del subcanal

El query funciona bien hasta este punto

```sql
SELECT e.primerApellido, e.primerNombre, sub.nombreTienda
FROM Empleados e
INNER JOIN EmpleadoTienda et ON e.id = et.idEmpleado 
INNER JOIN Subcanales sub ON sub.subcanal= et.idTienda
```

Resultado:

- Perez, Maria, Apple
- Angulo, jose, Apple
- Rojas, Pedro, Apple

El problema es cuando agrego un inner joint a la tabla ventasMovil ya que es un historico de ventas y me trae `todos los registros` y es lo que no quiero

```sql
SELECT e.primerApellido, e.primerNombre, sub.nombreTienda,vm.nom_subcanal
FROM Empleados e
INNER JOIN EmpleadoTienda et ON e.id = et.idEmpleado 
INNER JOIN Subcanales sub ON sub.subcanal= et.idTienda
INNER JOIN VentasMovil_tmp vm on vm.subcanal = sub.subcanal
```

El resultado que espero:

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

-Rojas, Pedro, Apple, INC apple

El resultado que me da:

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

-Perez, Maria, Apple, INC apple

- n perez Maria....

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

-Angulo, jose, Apple, INC apple

- n angulo jose....

Comment: Puede haber más de un  `nom_subcanal` por empleado? si es así, cual es te todos quisieras ver?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si es una tabla historica de ventas, en una tienda puede existir 1 o mas empleados, y durante un dia pueden hacer muchas ventas
Solo 1. lo que busco es verificar si el nombre de la tienda  en la tabla `subcanales` corresponde al mismo nombre en la tabla ventasMovil el nombre en esta tabla se llama `nomb_subcanal`

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres incluir la tabla de ventas en el join? Es decir, ¿qué dato quieres obtener de ella? Porque si no quieres ningún dato, no hace falta incluirla. Igual, dado que tienes una relación de muchos a muchos entre empleados y tiendas, un empleado puede aparecer tantas veces como tiendas tenga asociadas. Creo que es importante que definas con mayor claridad qué es lo que quieres obtener para poder ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: A ver.. agrega un `group by  e.primerApellido, e.primerNombre, sub.nombreTienda,vm.nom_subcanal` y seguramente lo resuelvas, pero tal vez no se la forma adecuada, si joineas por una tabla de la que no usas ningún dato, es probable que es tabla este de mas en la consulta.

Comment: Agrega -por lo menos- la estructura de la tabla del histórico de ventas.